# Chain Rule for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

Suppose, we have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}$. Also, let
\begin{align}
f_1(x)= f(x {\bf I})
\end{align}
where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and ${\bf I}$ is the identity matrix.

Now suppose that

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}f_1(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x {\bf I})=g(x{\bf I})=g_1(x)
\end{align}

My question: Can we do a chain rule of differentiation as follows. Let ${\bf h}(x): \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and we want to find
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}f({\bf h}(x))=??
\end{align}

I think the expression should be something like
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}f(h(x))= g({\bf h}(x)) {\rm det}(J({\bf h}(x)))
\end{align}
where $(J({\bf h}(x)))$ is the determinant of the Jacobian of ${\bf h}(x)$.
Is this correct?

Comment: Note that the derivative of $f$ equals $g$ only on a very small (one-dimensional) subset of $\mathbb R^{n \times n}$, namely the line spanned by the identity matrix. Away from that subset, $g$ and $f$ need not have anything to do with each other. Hence, $g(\mathbf{h}(x))$ should typically have nothing to do with $f(\mathbb{h}(x))$ since $\mathbb{h}(x)$ need not be anywhere near multiples of the identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your general case $f\circ h$ the chain rule says
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(h(x))=\sum_{i,j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial h_{ij}} \frac{\partial h_{ij}}{\partial x}$$

In your special case $h$ is given by $h_{ij}= x \delta_{ij}$ so 
$$ \frac{\partial h_{ij}}{\partial x} = \delta_{ij}$$ 
So you end up with

$$ \frac{d}{dx}f(h(x))= \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial h_{ii}} = \text{trace}\,\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial h_{ij}}\right)$$

Comment: (sorry, I used the summation convention in the first version, which you may not be familiar with).